# Removing duplicates and sorting list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list, I need to print the numbers in sorted order and remove any duplicates. I am using python 3.7.2

**My code:**

```
def sorted_elements(numbers):
    return sorted(set(numbers))

testcase = int(input())
while testcase > 0:
   numbers = input().split()
   l = sorted_elements(numbers)

   for x in l:
      print (x, end = ' ')

   print ()
   testcase -= 1
```

However, whenever my input consists of a 2 digit number, the logic fails.
Eg. for input of `2 1 43 2 5`, I get an output of `1 2 43 5`.

This work perfectly for single digit numbers. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: numbers is an list of strings convert it to integer , `numbers = map(int,input().split())`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, I had issues when I pasted the code. Anyway, it has been edited and an IndentationError should not come up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a slight modification. You are comparing strings instead of numbers, so try this instead:

```
def sorted_elements(numbers):
    return sorted(set(numbers))

testcase = int(input())
while testcase > 0:
   numbers = map(int, input().split())
   l = sorted_elements(numbers)

   for x in l:
      print (x, end = ' ')

   print ()
   testcase -= 1
```

If you want, you can also do:

```
numbers = (int(x) for x in input().split())
```

Comment: this is a homework questions withpout much effort - I generally avoid them - they get deleted eventually anyway. 1-liner: `print(' '.join(sorted(set(map(int,input().split())))))`

Comment: @PatrickArtner It is true that it can be done easily in one line, but I wanted to make the least modifications as possible to OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

You are going correct way with `set(numbers)` to remove duplicates. The problem comes from `sorted` with your `numbers` being list of `str`s not `int`s.

Try this:

```
x_numbers = input().split()
numbers = [int(x) for x in x_numbers]
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Don't you see `return sorted(set(numbers))` in the OP's question?

Comment: It was not clear to me you ment him to use your `numbers` instead in his code so I deemed the answer incomplete as answer to `Removing duplicates and sorting list python` - thanks for adding some context.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this in various aspects. Sort by numeric value using an appropriate key function, use a `for` loop if you know the number of iterations beforehand, utilize appropriate string utils like `str.join`, etc.

```
testcases = int(input())

for _ in range(testcases):
    print(' '.join(sorted(set(input().split()), key=int)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can keep it simple like this. This is a reference

```
input=raw_input() #took input as string
inputlist=input.split() #split the string to list
lsintegers = map(int, list(set(inputlist))) #remove duplicates converted each element to integer
lsintegers.sort() #sorted 
print(lsintegers)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it now:

```
    testcase = int(input())
    n=list(str(testcase))
    results = map(int, n)

    numbers= sorted(set(results))


    print(numbers)
```

code here:https://repl.it/repls/SeriousRosybrownApplicationprogrammer